# Clarifications on the discussion in Accelerated C++ header files

Tags: c++, compilation

I am reading Accelerated C++ Chapter 4: Organizing Programs and Data.  I came across the following piece of code, which is saved to a file called `median.cpp`:

```
// median.cpp file contents
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>
using std::domain_error;
using std::sort;
using std::vector;
// Compute the median of a vector<double>
double median(vector<double> vec)
{
// Code for what the median function does goes here
}
```

and then, later on on page 67., the authors discuss an include guard like below, which is saved to a file called median.h.

```
#ifndef GUARD_median_h
#define GUARD_median_h
// median.h - final version
#include<vector>
double median(std::vector<double>);
//
#endif
```

Are we supposed to "include" the `median.h` into `median.cpp` before compiling, like below?

```
// median.cpp file contents
#include "median.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>
using std::domain_error;
using std::sort;
using std::vector;
// Compute the median of a vector<double>
double median(vector<double> vec)
{
// Code for what the median function does goes here
}
```

I am asking this because, in section 4.3 where the authors discuss this topic, they have failed to mention how someone is supposed to make use of `median.cpp` and     `median.h` for compilation.

Comment: Yes: `median.cpp` should have `#include "median.h"` in it, so that the compiler can check that the definition of `median()` in the file matches the header.  Each source file that uses `median()` should also include `median.h` so that the compiler knows what the `median()` function is.  When it comes to compiling and linking, you will compile `median.cpp` into an object file `median.o` (or `median.obj` on a Windows platform), and your other source file(s) into corresponding object files, and then link the object files together to make the program that will run.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I don't see how "the compiler can check that the definition of median() in the file matches the header". In most cases a mismatch in the signature will be taken as overloading functions...

Comment: @T.C. Hmmm; yes, maybe so — chalk one up for good old fashioned C, where you do get that checking.  But if the definition doesn't match the declaration, the other source files only have the declaration to work with, so they are unaware of the (accidental) overload, and the problem is revealed at link time (with an unresolved external) instead of compile time.